# sprintf too many/few decimals

Tags: c++, printf

I must convert decimal numbers using a non-scientific (ie. no mantissa/exponent/E's) character string. My code looks like this:

```
/*!
\brief Converts a <em>XML Schema Decimal</em>
*/
char *ToDecimal(double val) const
{
    const size_t nMax = 200;
    char *doubleStr = new char[nMax];

    sprintf(doubleStr, "%1.6f", val);

    return doubleStr;
}
```

The problem is that when the input `val` is `1` then the function returns `1.000000` but I was hoping for a output of `1`. Also, if I change the code to `sprintf(doubleStr, "%1.0f", val);` then it correctly outputs `1`, but if the input `val` is changed to `0.000005` the output is `0`, and I was hoping the output would then be `0.000005`. So basically I want all output to be as short as possible and remove all unnessesary `0`'s. Is this possible with `sprintf`? I would like to support 3.4E +/- 38  range with this function.

Comment: So if the input is 1e-30, do you want the output to be 0.000000000000000000000000000001?

Comment: You'd have to write the code to convert it to a string and strip the zeros and return a string. You'd also have to pass the number of places if you want it to vary, because of course 0.1 as a constant is not actually equal to 0.1.

Comment: @anatolyg Yes, all the way down to 3.4E-38. Trying to implement support for XML Schema Decimal's. http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal-lexical-representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that c++ iostreams (specifically, `ostringstream`) are better suited for your task than `sprintf`.

Use the `std::fixed` manipulator to disable scientific notation. Use `std::setprecision` to specify precision (number of characters after decimal dot). In your case, precision of 45 places seems enough to represent all `float` numbers.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string convert(double x)
{
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << std::fixed << std::setprecision(45) << x;
    std::string result = buffer.str();

    return result;
}
```

In addition, to clean-up the result, remove any trailing zeros.

```
    size_t i = result.find_last_not_of('0');
    if (result[i] != '.')
        ++i;
    result.erase(i);
```

Note: the clean-up of trailing zeros will only work for numbers that are exactly representable (like 0.75 or 0.03125): for example, the number 0.1 is converted to `0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834`. One could use non-constant precision (depending on the magnitude of the number), but this is very tricky to get right.

Instead, it's possible to use the following ugly (and slow) hack: try converting the start of the string back to `double`, and cut the string if the result is equal to the initial number.

```
size_t i;
for (i = 1; i < result.size(); ++i)
{
    std::istringstream cut(result.substr(0, i));
    double temp;
    cut >> temp; // the verbose syntax could fit into one line 
    if (temp == x) // by using boost::lexical_cast
        break;
}
```

Comment: With VC++ 2012 `std::setprecision()` **must** be set to at least `46` when `x` is `FLT_MIN` - otherwise it just returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged C++, I assume you can use C++ features that are not available in C (if not, tell me and I'll delete this answer).

First, I suggest using a `std::string` instead of `char*` (this frees you from memory managing the buffer)? Second, I suggest using a `ostringstream` for the conversion:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string ToDecimal(double val) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << val;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: +1 for `std::ostringstream`, but you did not mention `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` so I accepted anatolyg's answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Inge Henriksen: Fair enough. No hard feelings ;-)